# Code Coverage for Web Applications?

Tags: webdriver, coverage, junit

Does anyone have any experience using code coverage tools for web applications?

I primarily work with Webdriver and JUnit, but I am not sure if we are covering all the possible cases.

This may overlap with test coverage.

Basically, how to ensure test coverage/code coverage for a website.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, user3249785.  What kind of research have you already done to figure this out?  Adding that information to your question will help us with our answers.

Comment: Also, are you talking about code coverage for the server side code, javascript or both?  There are very different solutions for each.

Comment: I'm looking for general advice at this point.

Answer (score 2):

For backend coverage (mostly java), we use Cobertura: http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/

The developers tend to use Emma, in Eclipse: http://emma.sourceforge.net/

For frontend (JavaScript), I've heard good things about ScriptCover: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2011/10/scriptcover-makes-javascript-coverage.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

All I could say is we cannot test code coverage completely and we would not know regarding that since we are QA / Testers and not developers. 
All we could do is we test the higher end functionality depending on the web application! And later all smaller chunks of the web application is being covered by the test cases you prepare. If you are knowing the code as per your question you are working mainly on webdriver and JUnit so this is an added advantage like you sit with the application and test end to end then later try to analyse if all the functionality are working perfectly. If you find any defect or any bug then "Code Coverage" isn't proper thats all! Bottom line is every button, tab, clicks etc should be covered in your test cases then its possible for complete coverage of the functionality ! 
If possible follow this link too as ans is written for the code coverage too : [When to use White box Testing in a software or a website?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/when-to-use-white-box-testing-in-a-software-or-a-website)
Hopefully you got the answer for your questions. If so then please let me know. Thanks !

Comment: Why can't we test code coverage? Being a 'tester' doesn't mean you can't access the code - or ask for coverage of tests to be measured

Comment: Hello Phil Kirkham, I never said that whether we could access the code or not. I just said that being a tester code coverage can be dependent on our test cases as well and it can be tested depending upon the Black or White box testing who are specialised with.