# How to get the test coverage from a GIS API tested with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a GIS API that used the OpenLayers 2 library.

I performed the unit tests with QUnit and the code coverage is done with BlanketJS. It works like a charm. :)

Now, I am writing the integration tests (automated testing) with Selenium WebDriver 2 (java version).

My current app is basically:

- an HTML page,
- a JavaScript file with the GIS API  (this has been tested with QUnit)
- a JavaScript file where I manage the elements of the HTML page, using jQuery and so on (I wanted to cover this file and know how much I have tested from it)

I have been reading about code coverage for Selenium WebDriver and I came across [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7691/code-coverage-for-web-applications), which is certainly a good solution.

But I think it means that I should run the tests on an other machine. Is there a simpler way to perform the code coverage of such a project? I mean, is there a way to do it on my machine, without installing SonarQube and stuff like that?

The app is quite small for now, so I would prefer a simpler way to do the test coverage of the JS file mentioned above.

Forgive me if this question sounds repeated or noob-like, but I am a newbie with Selenium WebDriver that is looking for simple things to start.

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did a Google search and came across [this blog post](https://innovatorsdelight.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/collecting-javascript-code-coverage-during-a-selenium-automation-test-run/) that seems to fit the bill. It goes over how to use JSCover with Selenium.

Comment: I have played around with JSCover in the past. It is certainly possible to run Selenium tests and gather the JSCover coverage results. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13868746/1088584